# Definition of "to take a chance on"-longman dictionary

Tags: meaning-in-context, definition

*He was taking a chance on a relatively new young actor.*(Example)

Definition of "to take a chance on"given by longman dictionary:-

**to do something that involves risks**

I think this definition not suitable and straightforward for this type of sentence.I am having difficulties understanding this sentence.

Comment: Why do you think it's "not suitable"? We don't have the full context for *He was taking a chance on* [or ***with***] *a relatively new young actor,* but probably "he" is a film / theatre director. Using a "relatively new young actor" is potentially ***risky*** for a director. We *know* a well-established "big name" actor is good at his craft; that's how he *became* established. But a relatively new young actor might be problematic in all sorts of ways (gets drunk on set, forgets his lines, argues with the director, whatever). The director is taking a chance / risk by using him.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "to do something.." How to know what to do with relatively new young actor. "Can you make me understand the sentence by using definition given"?

Comment: You must bear in mind that the target readers for Longman's Dictionary are native Anglophones, not people from other cultures who speak other languages. If it's not obvious to you that "he" in the example is likely to be someone like a (film, stage) ***director***, then that example sentence is no use to you. If you ***do*** understand that, it's not clear to me what you ***don't*** understand about the example usage. But I can't see why you don't understand the definition itself *(**to do something that involves risks**)*, let alone why you don't understand the example ***illustrating*** it.

Comment: *...to take a chance on X = **to bet, wager, assume, hope,...** that X will be successful*.

Comment: Your definition is understandable but the dictionary gives:to do something..... Btw thanks

Comment: Sam, the 'doing something' here is employing the new young actor in a play or film. The risk is of him or her not doing a good job.

Comment: To take a chance on means to take a risk. If you sit in the sun for long, you take a chance on a sunburn. You risk a sunburn.

Comment: Too bad that gotube  removed my answer. I posted it to show how common an expression this is. You really overstep yourself.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The points from the various commenters are valid and can be considered answers to your questions.  I am only concluding the matter.

> He was *taking a chance* on a relatively new young actor.

Your query seems to revolve round the infinitive *to do something* in the definition of *take a chance*:

> *to do something* that involves risks

You query how
***to take** a chance* can be made equal to ***to do** something*, and ask *How to know what to do with [the] relatively new young actor*.

By employing the new young actor, the task *to do something* is done:

> **to employ** the new young actor = **to do** something

There is no more thing *to do* with the relatively new young actor.  (This answers your query *How to know what to do with [the] relatively new young actor*.)

Comment: to take a chance on [something] is an idiom.